# Async Calls to Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-4

Anyone found a good way to make asynchronous calls to the db via entity framework? Use background worker thread? This is a WPF application.

I know in RIA services there is a loadcompleted event that does not seem to exist in entity framework's object context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've written a blog post about async calls via commanding in a WPF application

http://devblog.terminto.com/2010/11/03/threading-as-command-in-mvvm/

At work I use the same technique and do calls to DB (EF4).

Is this useful, or are you asking about more entity framework-specific async methods?

Comment: Thanks for the great article.  Do you have a project file? thanks.